# Vba Excel .SaveAs xlCSV object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

When trying to .SaveAs a worksheet through VBA with ojbExcel, I get the object defined error (1004) that a lot of people have already had. What's annoying about this case is that it worked fine before, but started giving me this error yesterday. I've researched this error and I've tried most solutions but to no avail. 
The code in question is:

```
fileLoc = Session.GetOpenFilename("Excel (*.xls*), *.xls*")
If fileLoc = "" Then Exit Sub
Set oXl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
fpath = fileLoc
spath = "H:\Download\" 
sheetnum = InputBox("Please insert the sheet number(Count from left to        right).", "Select Sheet!")
fdir = Dir(fpath)
If Trim(fdir) <> "" Then
If Right(fdir, 5) = ".xlsx" Then

    Set oWorkbook = oXl.workbooks.Open(fileLoc, False, True)
    Set oWorksheet = oWorkbook.worksheets(sheetnum)
    oXl.Activeworkbook.worksheets(sheetnum).SaveAs FileName:=spath &    oWorksheet.Name, FileFormat:=xlCSV
    'other options I have tried:
    'oWorksheet.SaveAs spath & oWorkbook.worksheets(sheetnum).Name, xlCSV
    'oWorksheet.SaveAs spath & oWorksheet.Name, xlCSV 'this last one worked previously
End if 
End if 

oWorkbook.Close
Set oWorkbook = Nothing
oXl.Quit
Set oXl = Nothing
```

What possibly changed that this doesn't work anymore?
Excel 2010, script ran from a Reflection terminal on Citrix client.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming this code isn't actually running from Excel, in which case the `xlCSV` constant won't work unless you've set a reference to the `Microsoft Excel xx.x Objects` library (i.e. Early Binding). You've used late binding and so `xlCSV` will be treated as an undeclared variant type with a null value.

---

Use the literal [value of the xlFileFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) constant instead:

```
oXl.Activeworkbook.worksheets(sheetnum).SaveAs FileName:=spath & oWorksheet.Name, FileFormat:=6
```

Comment: Thank you! I have absolutely no idea how this worked this week, maybe because I didn't close my objExcel properly (had problems with this previously), but it now works. Thanks!